# Why does this Shiny App not display dataframe using RStudio?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a list of data frames, `ls_df`, comprising two dataframes from the `datasets` package.

I am trying to load these two dataframes into a Shiny app using the code below. However, it does not work, with the error message `no item called "ls_df" on the search list` being returned. Does anyone know how to fix?

```
ls_df <- list(datasets::airmiles,
datasets::AirPassengers)


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("ls_df", label = "Dataset", choices = ls("ls_df")),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- get(input$ls_df, "ls_df")
    summary(dataset)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    dataset <- get(input$ls_df, "ls_df")
    dataset
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list needs the names:

```
library(shiny)
ls_df <- list(airmiles=datasets::airmiles,AirPassengers=datasets::AirPassengers)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("ls_df", label = "Dataset", choices = names(ls_df)),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- ls_df[[input$ls_df]]
    summary(dataset)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    dataset <- ls_df[[input$ls_df]]
    dataset
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things wrong:

1. Your list needs names, as discussed in PorkChop's answer. If this were the only required change, then PorkChop's answer would suffice.
2. `get(input$ls_df, "ls_df")` is an error. This should be rather clear, though, since it prevents the shiny interface from starting. This error is because the `envir=` argument of `ls` and `get` require an *object*, not the `character` name of an object. (One *could* go "inception" and use `ls(get("ls_df"))` and similarly for `get`, but that hardly seems necessary or useful.)

   ```r
   ls_df <- list(airmiles=datasets::airmiles,                       # <-- named list
                 AirPassengers=datasets::AirPassengers)


   ui <- fluidPage(
     selectInput("ls_df", label = "Dataset", choices = ls(ls_df)),  # <-- no quotes
     verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
     tableOutput("table")
   )

   server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$summary <- renderPrint({
       dataset <- get(input$ls_df, ls_df)                           # <-- no quotes
       summary(dataset)
     })

     output$table <- renderTable({
       dataset <- get(input$ls_df, ls_df)                           # <-- no quotes
       dataset
     })
   }
   ```